# How to find frequency of each class within a group in R?

Tags: r, aggregate, frequency

I have the following data:

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "   id    country
    1   IT
    1   IT
    1   USA
    2   USA
    2   FR
    2   IT
    3   USA
    3   USA
    3   IT
    3   FR", header = T)
```

I need to find frequency of each country within every ID. So, the desired output is:

```
       id  IT  USA  FR
        1   2   1   0
        2   1   1   1
        3   1   2   1
```

I know how to calculate with count() the number of rows for each id but I don't know how to display by each country.
Thanks for help!

Comment: What's wrong with `table(df)`?

Comment: how to do table() for each Id?

Comment: Just `table(df)`. It does do it for each id

Comment: Indeed. I have more than two columns in df so it got me confused. Thanks!

Comment: @Roland gave you the best answer. I'm so used of other packages that I forget there might be a more simple way of doing something with base R. In this case a lot more efficient too.

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  count(country) %>% # count having grouped by ids
  spread(country, n) # we spread the values, in order to have long format

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id    FR    IT   USA
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1    NA     2     1
2     2     1     1     1
3     3     1     1     2
```

This if you want to replace `NA` with `0`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  count(country) %>% 
  spread(country, n) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) # mutate applied for all variables, where we find NA
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
     id    FR    IT   USA
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     2     1
2     2     1     1     1
3     3     1     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with `xtabs` in simple way :

```
xtabs(~df$id+df$country) or 

xtabs(~df+country,data=df)
```

**output:**

```
     df$country
df$id FR IT USA
    1  0  2   1
    2  1  1   1
    3  1  1   2
```